# Search inside a JSON array using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I wanna search for a certain value inside a JSON array but I only get an error message.

For example I wanna search for a certain country inside the JSON array and select only the `user_id` of the user if the country id contained in the array.

I tried using `JSON_CONTAINS`:

```
<?php 
    $query = "SELECT user_id FROM user 
              WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(user_info, 'us', '$.country')";
    $row = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($conn));;
    while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($row )){
        echo $results['user_id']."<br>";
    }
?>
```

My Database Table "user"

```
|user_id|username|user_info
|      1|     xxx|{"language":["en","fr"],"country":["us"]}
|      2|     xxx|{"language":["de"],"country":["au"]}
|      3|     xxx|{"language":["ja"],"country":["us","jp"]}
```

My error message

> Error: Invalid JSON text in argument 2 to function json_contains: "Invalid value." at position 0.

Comment: searching with PHP is no different from searching in mysql. you have to refer to mysql documentation related to json_contains

Comment: `$.country` < that appears to be a typo and isn't shown where it is defined (as).

Comment: `['user_id ']` < the space in there counts as a character and you should also be getting an undefined index warning about it.

Comment: It isn't recommended to store data in there like that, using comma separated values. There are ways to normalize a database for this.

Comment: [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Answer (score 2):

[`Json_Contains()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) expects the Second argument to be a valid JSON Document, while you are passing a string.

> An error occurs if target or candidate is not a valid JSON document

Use `'["us"]'` instead of `"us"`. [View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ryjt7nvRgS1zjYv2D4AShD/0):

```
SET @jsn := '{"language":["en","fr"],"country":["us"]}';

SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(@jsn, '["us"]', '$.country');

| JSON_CONTAINS(@jsn, '["us"]', '$.country') |
| ------------------------------------------ |
| 1                                          |
```

But then, if I understand correctly, you are trying to find those JSON doc wherein the array corresponding to `country` key contains `'us'`. `JSON_CONTAINS()` cannot be used to achieve this directly. You will need to use a combination of [`JSON_EXTRACT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) and [`JSON_SEARCH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search). Note that you are only looking for a match, so second argument can be `one` in `Json_Search()` function:

```
SET @jsn := '{"language":["en","fr"],"country":["us"]}';

SELECT 
  JSON_SEARCH(JSON_EXTRACT(@jsn, '$.country'), 'one', 'us');

| JSON_SEARCH(JSON_EXTRACT(@jsn, '$.country'), 'one', 'us') |
| --------------------------------------------------------- |
| "$[0]"                                                    |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ryjt7nvRgS1zjYv2D4AShD/2)

Now, `Json_Search` returns NULL if any of the json_doc, search_str, or path arguments are NULL; no path exists within the document; or search_str is not found. So, you will need to use `IS NOT NULL` in your `WHERE` clause. Use the following query instead:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM user 
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(JSON_EXTRACT(user_info, '$.country'), 'one', 'us') IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You missed something. See a comment I left under their question, something about an undefined index ;-)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner there might be more errors; I am not evaluating the PHP code, but suggesting a fix for the MySQL query